# Exporting Illustrator to layered PSD

Tags: export, photoshop, layer, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to export a Illustrator design into a Layerd Photoshop PSD file. But its getting exported as a flat image. i have selected the following options while exporting.

[image]

But when i get the file in the Photoshop i am getting only one layer.

[image]

Is there any particular way to stack the content in AI file to export it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if your original file in Illustrator is in RGB mode as well. Simply go to File > Document color mode. If it is in CMYK, it won't export layers.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using PS CC2014.

It's as simple as using (in Photoshop) the *Open As* command in the *File* menu.  This opens the .AI file in PS ass a layered file.  You can then save and edit as needed.

Comment: Doesn't work -- says "the document is not a valid PSD file."

Comment: ^ Confirmed, does not work